# Complex tab and brace alignment rules with clang-format

Tags: c, clang-format

I work at a company with specific brace indentation requirements. 2 spaces are used for tabs from the function's braces, and the first brace in a pair is always found on its own line. Clang-format handles this just fine.

However, statements such as ifs and whiles have some pretty unique rules.

- 1 space is used for indentation from the if statement's brace pair to the code.
- Braces are indented one space in from the first "if" if no "else" statement is present, and two spaces in if one is present.
- Else's are indented one space in from the first "if".

Here is an example illustrating the desired formatting:

```
void func()
{
  if (1)
   {
    // code
   }

  if (1)
    {
     // code
    }
   else if (1)
    {
     // code
    }
   else
    {
     // code
    }
}
```

I don't think clang-format supports this by default. Is there any way to added complex custom rules to clang-format to format documents with these types of requirements?

Comment: This is madness, whoever came up with it with it wasn't a competent C programmer. You should be pushing to adopt a sane style instead. Industry standard means no indention of braces, brace on same line as statement or on the next line _not_ indented (either is fine), _consistent_ indention of either 2 or 4 spaces. Basically there might be a reason why clang-format doesn't support this, because nobody in the world is using this style. The chances that your company standard was written by some genius who knows better than all programmers ever using C during the past 50 years is pretty slim.

Comment: I'm a bit disappointed by the rude/ignorant response. The lead dev has been coding for 40+ years. The company ships an internationally-used mapping package with some of the fastest data management algorithms.

This formatting style was developed 30+ years ago: when there were barely any "standards" or programming books, when editors didn't have undo, and when resolution made it hard to see if an "if" had a matching else quickly. It wouldn't make sense for a project of 6+ million lines of code to suddenly switch standards.

A simple "no, this isn't supported" would've sufficed. @Lundin

Comment: I don't know much about clang-format so I'll refrain from answering; this was just a comment. But you can't really say that no formatting styles existed. K&R 1st edition featured a style still common today: first brace on same line as the statement, then 4 spaces indention, then final brace at the same indention level as the the statement. This style was as close as canon as you would get pre-standardization. Nowadays placing the brace on a line of its own is perhaps more common, either is fine. Anything but these two styles is highly questionable though, like it or not.

Comment: @Lundin this bracing style is the GNU C standard's. It is the default style of GNU indent (used by generations of C programmers to format their code and what we got before clang-format was available for C and C++ code formatting). By dismissing this style you are dismissing C/C++ heritage, UNIX hackers have used this style for decades.

Comment: @wirrbel No, it is not the correct style to use for Linux and never was. Source: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html. Linux is what, 30 years old by now? Nor is it the style used by K&R. Nor is it a style used in Windows. Or anywhere else, afaik.

Comment: The style predates Linux and we never talked here about the Linux kernel style guide. Look at eMacs https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lib/cloexec.c  or see GNU find https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/findutils.git/tree/lib/extendbuf.c

Answer (score 0):

https://releases.llvm.org/14.0.0/tools/clang/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#configurable-format-style-options

`GNU` style should be your best bet I think. It will differ in using 2 spaces to indent the branches of if clauses and loops. Potentially you can inherit from the `GNU` style and override the specific setting there.